# Handsontable Not able to start

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I am trying to use handsontable. I downloaded its source code and trying simple test.

Code:

[image]
While running this I am getting error : script error.
[image: Error while using]

Comment: Although screenshots are better than nothing, try to minimize their use if you can copy and paste the text (once you paste in code selekt it and indent it using the `{}` (code sample) button). That way someone willing to help can more easily run your code if applicable, and the site can actually search for text within you code and error message.

Answer (score 0):

You may be using an old version of IE. Try in the latest version of IE or chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Your URI looks incorrect. You have two slashes after the `.com`. Try removing one.